# How do I find sum of the series?

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I calculated the radius of convergence is $\frac{1}{3}$. Can anyone suggest to me the last part of the question that is the sum of the series.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Write separately the odd and even terms, as $2n$ and $2n+1$
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty(2+(-1)^k)^kz^k=\sum_{n=0}^\infty3^{2n}z^{2n}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty1^{2n+1}z^{2n+1}$$

Comment: You are too fast for the old man ! Cheers ;-)